# Counting PDF pages in ROR with Docsplit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, docsplit

I need to get the count of pages in PDF files stored in Ruby on Rails 5.2.3 ActiveStorage using Docsplit.

I'm uploading PDF documents using Ruby on Rails ActiveStorage. I understand these documents are stored as a blob. I was hoping I could pass the reference to the PDF file to Docsplit with something like:

```rb
pages = Docsplit.extract_length(@car_record.crecord)
```

But the above resulted in an error:

```
no implicit conversion of ActiveStorage::Attached::One into String
```

Answer (score 1):

`Docsplit.extract_length` expects a string (presumably a path to a local file), and `@car_record.crecord` returns an ActiveRecord object.

You should be able to do something like,

```
file = @car_record.crecord.download_blob_to_tempfile
Docsplit.extract_length(file.path)
```

Edit: `ActiveStorage::Downloading` is being removed in 6.1. Try something like the following:

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new 
tempfile.binmode

begin
  @car_record.crecord.download { |chunk| tempfile.write(chunk) } 
  tempfile.flush
  tempfile.rewid
ensure 
  tempfile.close!
end

Docsplit.extract_length(tempfile.path)
```

Comment: To do this, I think I need to include ActiveStorage::Downloading somewhere, but I'm not sure where?

Comment: Looks like it's being removed in 6.1. I've updated my answer.